# RxJava and retrofit and combining results

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I'm pretty new to RxJava and am struggling with how to compose Observables.

I need to make 2 requests (independently) and retrieve the 2 models from the 2 REST services.

The next step is to create a third model from the prior 2 models.

Here are my 2 Observables and a Function:

```
Observable<ProfileModel> userProfile(@Path("token") String token);
Observable<OnDemandRules> getRules();
Func2<OnDemandRules, ProfileModel, UserDetails> createUserDetails(final ProfileModel profileModel, final OnDemandRules onDemandRules)
```

I guess I need to create another Observer but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip(zipWith)` to combine results from different Observables, such as

```
userProfile(...).zipWith(getRules, createUserDetails)
```